# Self-hosted photo management webapp with facial recognition, duplicates elimination

Tags: linux, images, photography, self-hosted, facial-recognition

Whenever I think of my piles of photos with multiple duplicates of each, I get a little stressed and put it off for another year.  Time to do something about it, and am looking for some software to assist.

User needs:

- Linux OS and ideally open source
- Identify and eliminate duplicate pics
- Facial recognition
- Web access (direct access is not required and headless is acceptable)
- Reasonable lifetime expectancy
- Editing capability might be nice but is not required
- Ability to give specific users ability to view (reasonable security goes without saying)
- Intuitive tagging